# Annotating a rectangle in R with ggplot2 for a graph in log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I'm trying to annotate a rectangle in R through ggplot2 for a graph that is in log scale. Here's the annotate layer I am adding:

```
annotate("rect",xmin=293.3, xmax=312, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill='gray')
```

Of course, I understand the negative infinity is causing problems since it's a log scale and there is no negative value. Since I am pre-specifying my limits on the y-scale, anyone have any thoughts on how to create a 'negative infinity' to infinity rectangle using this method or another method?

Comment: log scale does not take negative values. Change `ymin` to `0` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R gives `log(0)` as `-Inf`, so you can use `ymin = 0` to generate `-Inf` when logged.

Demonstration on built-in data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 2, xmax = 4, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, fill = 'gray') +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I've accepted the response